# How to edit database table (in memory) at run time using JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Hi I have huge table which is coming from network in chunks. Before storing into database I want to do some operations on it like firing update queries etc. Now how do I fire queries using JDBC without storing table into database.

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three options:

1. If your database is transactional and if the changes fit within the database transactional boundary ("rollback segment"), just insert the data but do not commit the transaction. You can invoke your analysis queries and commit or rollback the transaction later depeding on the results.
2. Store the data from the network in a file (e.g CSV) and read it later for analysis (e.g. using a [CSV JDBC driver](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/)) prior inserting it into your database.
3. Use a temporary table for inserting you data. If the data is good, just copy the records from the temporary table into the real table and drop the temporary table.